# Klipper Input frequency Chart not making sense

Tags: klipper

In all of the guides i've read it says to read this chart and wherever the peak is for your axis you tested that is the number you set for your freq. However, my chart on the X axis the peak is about 17 but the chart says the recommended value is 39. Why?

[image]